# How to show VisualizePanel (weka) using JavaFx?

Tags: java, swing, javafx, weka

I'm trying to display a VisualizePanel chart from the Weka API on JavaFX.
I've found some code that uses SWING, I want to do the same thing but on JavaFx.
Swing code below that does the trick:

```
VisualizePanel visPanel = new VisualizePanel();
PlotData2D pd1 = new PlotData2D(data);
String relationName = data.relationName();
pd1.setPlotName(relationName);
visPanel.setMasterPlot(pd1);

final javax.swing.JFrame jf = new javax.swing.JFrame("Title: " + relationName);
jf.setSize(1000, 800);
jf.getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());
jf.getContentPane().add(visPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
jf.addWindowListener(new java.awt.event.WindowAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void windowClosing(java.awt.event.WindowEvent e) {
        jf.dispose();
    }
});
jf.setVisible(true);
```

How would I do the same thing using JavaFX?
This particular line from the swing code seems to be the critical part that I can't seem to replicate using JavaFX:

```
jf.getContentPane().add(visPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

Trying to add the VisualizePanel object to a layout pane doesn't quite work.

```
Pane pane = new Pane();
pane.getChildren().add(visPanel);
```

Doesn't work...How would I got about adding the visPanel to a pane on JavaFX like they did using Swing above?

Comment: work through a tutorial on mixing Swing and fx - namely JFXPanel

Comment: [Embedding Swing Content in JavaFX Applications](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/8/embed_swing/jfxpub-embed_swing.htm)